# Why function inside a component is executing before componentDidMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have the next component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Navbar from "../Navbar";
import Modelado from "../app/ModeladoDeDatos";
import Grafica from "./Grafica";
import { Grid, Paper } from "@material-ui/core";
import { borrarConfig } from "../../actions/config.actions";
import history from "../../history";

import "../../static/css/Graficas.css";
import { getMyConnections } from "../../actions/connection.actions";

class Graficas extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getMyConnections();
  }

  renderGrafica = () => {
    return this.props.conexiones.map(conexion => {
      return Object.values(conexion.configurations).map((config, index) => {
        const modelo = new Modelado(config.result, config.values);
        return (
          <Grid
            key={index}
            item
            xs={6}
            onDoubleClick={() =>
              history.push(`/grafica/${conexion.id}/${config.id}`)
            }
          >
            <Paper>
              <Grafica
                configId={config.id}
                conexionId={conexion.id}
                nombre={config.name}
                modelo={modelo.construirDatos()}
                borrar={this.props.borrarConfig}
                menu={["Añadir al dashboard", "Eliminar"]}
              />
            </Paper>
          </Grid>
        );
      });
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <Grid container spacing={3} className="graficas">
          {this.renderGrafica()}
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { conexiones: Object.values(state.conexiones) };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { borrarConfig, getMyConnections }
)(Graficas);
```

When I try to render this component, the `renderGrafica` method is executed before the `componentDidMount` method, and this makes my application fail because I can't get the data from the redux store because the fetching occurs in the `componentDidMount`  call.
The redux action method where the fetching occurs looks like this:

```
export const getMyConnections = () => {
  console.log("me activo");
  return async dispatch => {
    const response = await requireAuthActions.get("/db/conexion");
    dispatch({ type: GET_MY_CONNECTIONS, payload: response.data });
  };
};
```

`componentDidMount` method calls a redux action who is a async call to an API.

Shouldn't the `componentDidMount` call execute before the component gets rendered?

Comment: You're calling `renderGrafica` from the main `render` function. Maybe try adding a check before calling `renderGrafica`

Comment: But is not supposed that the render function executes after componentDidMount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `componentDidMount` is run after the first render of the component. [From React's docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount):

> `componentDidMount()` is invoked immediately after a component is mounted (inserted into the tree). Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request.

Take a look at ["The Component Lifecycle"](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle) of React's Docs to learn more about it. Here is the list of functions called in order when mounting a component:

- `constructor()`
- `static getDerivedStateFromProps()`
- `render()`
- `componentDidMount()`

`componentDidMount()` is still the best place to make a network request, as the docs say. So, if you need the data from the `this.props.getMyConnections()` call to return before rendering the component from `renderGrafica` you should add a flag that waits for them to be available, before running the function.

I hope it helps.

Comment: So it doesn't matters that is the first time rendering the component, I have to add the flag to wait for the response of the request?

Comment: The thing is, even if you run it before the `render`, say at the `constructor` method, you are triggering a race condition. Since there is no way of being certain that the network request will resolve before the `render` is made. So, yes. You should add a flag (or some other logic) to avoid this issue.